# How to remove a pair of quotes from a string in python

Tags: python

I was webscraping craigslist and I managed to get my code to return the title of craigslist posts but when it would return I would get something like this:

`<div class="title">2022 Specialized Stumpjumper Evo Expert</div>`

When I try to remove all the characters but the name of the post it gives me an error because there are already double quotes in the string.

I was wondering how to remove these double quotes?

I tried using the replace() function but when I used it it would just give me an error because I can't nest double quotes inside double quotes. Im new to python so I'm not exactly sure what else I can do.

Comment: You should provide an example of what you've tried.  While we're happy to help you, we are generally not interested in writing your algorithms *for* you.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
'"apple"'
>>> b = a.replace('"', '')
>>> b
'apple'
```

Note that line 2 is replacing any double quote with an empty string. Remaining single quotes are good.